# Scraping Meteor with Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, meteor, web-scraping

I want to scrap some data from site easydrop.ru. I don't have much experience, so, I faced with some problems.

**Step 1:** Firstly, I have tried to load and parce this page using `requests.get` from requests lib and parce it with lxml. That was a fail, because there are mostly JS generated content. So I had only a small part, mostly the information about the page.

**Step 2:** My second attempt was using PyQt application for JS generation:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from lxml import html

# Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()



def getFinalHtml(url):
    r = Render(url)
    result = r.frame.toHtml()
    final = html.fragment_fromstring(result, 'root')
    return final
```

That was better, but still unsuccessfull - the page was fine now, However, the page does not contain any data (number of current users, items, etc)

This site uses the Meteor framework and values are getting by and the value obtained by communicating with them without reloading the page.

**Step 3:** At the moment I'm at a dead end and can not imagine how I can get the content of the page for further parsing :(

**I have only 2 ideas how to get data from this pages:**

**1)** *Load pages in Python (extension of step 2) and parce them usign lxml (Unfortunately, i don't know how to improve the loader to get values from meteor)*

**2)** *Use meteor functions in python to load data from this site (users\items) without html*

I have some ideas about second solution
I'm trying to do something with https://github.com/hharnisc/python-meteor lib. But I got into a dead end even when you try to start it:

I have a line from .js script on this site:

```
Meteor.startup(function (e) {
        return function () {
            return t(), Meteor.setInterval(t, 1e3), e.socket = io("https://ws.easydrop.ru", {transports: ["websocket"]})
        }
```

So, I have tried some variants

`client = MeteorClient('http://ws.easydrop.ru:3000/websocket')`

`client = MeteorClient('http://ws.easydrop.ru:3000/')`

`client = MeteorClient('http://ws.easydrop.ru:443/')`

`client = MeteorClient('http://ws.easydrop.ru:443/websocket/')`

But i have an error in py:

```
    raise ValueError("Invalid scheme: %s" % scheme)
ValueError: Invalid scheme: https
```

What should i do to work with it?

Comment: you can use `seleniumhq` to scrape javascript based sites such as meteor.

Comment: You can study the api calls the page makes and call them in turn with python's request. That won't fill the whole html page though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium or phantomjs work quite well for this there is a handy guide here:

http://toddhayton.com/2015/02/03/scraping-with-python-selenium-and-phantomjs/